# recreating timeline view

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In https://www.orgmode.org/Changes_old.html, it is said that

> #### Org Timeline
>
> This feature has been removed. Use a custom agenda view, possibly narrowed to current buffer to achieve a similar functionality.

This feature, with `org-agenda-log-mode`, showed you the time you clocked (in the `LOGBOOK`) which also allowed you to find when you had e.g. forgotten to clock some time and/or showed overlaps:

```
  [...]
  docs:       23:55-23:58 Clocked:   (0:00) task 1
Wednesday  19 May 2021
  docs:        0:00-10:06 Clocked:   (1:06) task 5
  docs:       10:06-10:24 Clocked:   (0:18) task 2
  docs:       10:24-11:40 Clocked:   (1:29) task 1
  docs:       11:53-11:58 Clocked:   (0:05) task 1
  docs:       12:13-12:46 Clocked:   (0:33) task 1
  docs:       12:50-12:58 Clocked:   (0:08) task 1
  docs:       13:39-14:00 Clocked:   (2:42) task 4
  docs:       14:00-16:21 Clocked:   (2:21) task 1
  docs:       16:21-23:36 Clocked:   (2:15) [[http://example.com][task with link]]
Thursday   20 May 2021
  docs:        2:18- 5:04 Clocked:   (0:46) task 1
  docs:        6:28- 8:00 Clocked:   (0:32) task 3
  docs:        8:00- 8:31 Clocked:   (0:31) task 1
```

How would you do this ?

Comment: I vaguely remember timeline view (and its demise), but I no longer remember anything else about it. Since it's probably not possible to recreate it exactly, can you describe what you would like to see? That's probably going to work better in generating an answer than asking about a long-gone feature. Or you might ask on the Org mode ML, where the person who wrote (probably - I don't know for sure) the snippet above is still active (I'm assuming that it is the same person who put the timeline feature out of its misery): he might be able to enlighten you.

Comment: @NickD : visuals are added (from an old emacs)

Comment: Does viewing the Log or Log-all (`vl` or `vL`) in the agenda provide what you need?

Comment: @mankoff : that view didn't show anything except the day headers